# EntityFieldQuery fieldCondition Date not working as expected

Tags: entities

No matter what i try i cant get EntityFieldQuery to work i have a date and i need to check if it is between the start date and end date of a date field that is set to unlimited values.. it should be at least between any one.. here is what i got.. can anybody help me?

UPDATE 10/26/2016:
So from what I found doing some more googling to do what I want I need to use delta_group so I added it to the code below but it doesn't seem to be working. Anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
    $myDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
          ->entityCondition('bundle', 'caregiver_db')
          ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
          ->fieldCondition('field_available_dates', 'value', $myDate, '>=', 0)
          ->fieldCondition('field_available_dates', 'value2', $myDate, '<=', 0);

    $results = $query->execute();
```

Comment: you're using the same date twice - this query will only match dates values like Y-m-d 00:00:00

Comment: it needs to be the same date.. because the same date needs to be between the start date and the end date.. and i've tried Y-m-d H:i:s already and that didnt work.. btw the date field is set to date.. as apposed to date (ISO) or date (unix)

Comment: so >= Y-m-d 00:00:00  and <= Y-m-d 23:59:59 does not work ? and you have entries in the database ?

Comment: yes there are several entries.. i've tried this specific string before "2016-10-30T14:02Z" and it returned an node but that node didnt have a date entry for the 30th of October 2016.. so i'm at a complete loss.. this just doesn't make any kind of sense

Comment: so actually i just tried Y-m-d H:i:s again and it seems to be working now.. i'm not sure what was wrong before.. maybe a typo? thanx for your help though

Comment: actually i just tried it again at the edge of the range i've set in the node and it doesnt seem to be working exactly..

Comment: i think i see whats going on here.. its giving me results that are of the endDate of one entry and the startDate of a different entry.. rather than between the startDate and endDate of the same date entry

Comment: So i've done some more research and from what i find its saying if i want two different fieldConditions to check by the same row i need to use the delta_group property.. but even then it still doesnt work..

Comment: can you show how you use the delta_group property ?

Comment: I updated the code example above

Comment: have you tried a string as deltagroup too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the final issue I was having was the operators I was using. Had to go <= on value and >= value2. I had it the other way around before. Here is the code that worked.

```
$myDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'caregiver_db')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
      ->fieldCondition('field_available_dates', 'value', $myDate, '<=', 0)
      ->fieldCondition('field_available_dates', 'value2', $myDate, '>=', 0);

$results = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the ***BETWEEN*** operator, like:

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';
$toDate = date('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59';
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->entityCondition('bundle', 'caregiver_db')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
      ->fieldCondition('field_available_dates', 'value', array($fromDate, $toDate), 'BETWEEN');
$results = $query->execute();
```

Also just go for the value if it's not a start/enddate field.